# how to write a phonegap custom dialer app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to write a phonegap / cordova app which dials a number, but uses a custom phone screen (not the regular android / iphone screen). Can this be done? Do I need to write a plugin for it?

Thanks.

Comment: not possible on iOS, not sure about android

Comment: According to what I read it's impossible in android. The other option is to use a custom screen which hides the in-call screen but I am having problems doing this.